# Deploy Gatsby + Contentful website to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, contentful

I've built simple blog website using Gatsby and Contentful CMS.
Now I am gonna deploy it to Netlify but met a build error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered such an error before.
It is because I didn't add environment variables into Netlify settings.
You may have env values in your project such as contentful spaceId, access token, etc.
Please check it again if you added it or not.

Go to Netlify settings -> Build & deploy -> Environment section

[image: environment variables]